# mvn site with Wildfly 8.1.0 BOM producing errors

Tags: maven-3, wildfly-8, maven-site-plugin

I have a pom.xml that uses a BOM of Wildfly 8.1.0 Final.

If I run a mvn clean install I have no problem at all.  But when I try to run site goal I recieve an error as if Maven was trying to retrieve some artifacts.  I am looking around but lots of suggestions seems to not solve my situation, like changing the BOM definition.

This is my stacktrace when I run site

```
[WARNING] Unable to create Maven project for org.wildfly:wildfly-client-all:pom:8.1.0.Final from repository.
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Error resolving project artifact: Failure to find org.wildfly:wildfly-client-all:pom:8.1.0.Final in http://sienadesenv.azulseguros.com.br:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced for project org.wildfly:wildfly-client-all:pom:8.1.0.Final
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:299)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:236)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.buildFromRepository(DefaultMavenProjectBuilder.java:251)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.RepositoryUtils.getMavenProjectFromRepository(RepositoryUtils.java:298)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.getDependencyRow(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:260)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.renderDependenciesForScope(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.renderDependenciesForAllScopes(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:157)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.renderSectionProjectDependencies(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:150)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.dependencies.renderer.DependencyManagementRenderer.renderBody(DependencyManagementRenderer.java:136)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReportRenderer.render(AbstractMavenReportRenderer.java:83)
    at org.apache.maven.report.projectinfo.DependencyManagementReport.executeReport(DependencyManagementReport.java:124)
    at org.apache.maven.reporting.AbstractMavenReport.generate(AbstractMavenReport.java:255)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.ReportDocumentRenderer.renderDocument(ReportDocumentRenderer.java:219)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.renderModule(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:319)
    at org.apache.maven.doxia.siterenderer.DefaultSiteRenderer.render(DefaultSiteRenderer.java:135)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.renderLocale(SiteMojo.java:175)
    at org.apache.maven.plugins.site.SiteMojo.execute(SiteMojo.java:138)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.resolution.ArtifactResolutionException: Failure to find org.wildfly:wildfly-client-all:pom:8.1.0.Final in http://sienadesenv.azulseguros.com.br:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifacts(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:262)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultRepositorySystem.resolveArtifact(DefaultRepositorySystem.java:295)
    at org.apache.maven.project.DefaultProjectBuilder.build(DefaultProjectBuilder.java:288)
    ... 37 more
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.transfer.ArtifactNotFoundException: Failure to find org.wildfly:wildfly-client-all:pom:8.1.0.Final in http://sienadesenv.azulseguros.com.br:8081/nexus/content/groups/public/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of nexus has elapsed or updates are forced
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.newException(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:232)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultUpdateCheckManager.checkArtifact(DefaultUpdateCheckManager.java:206)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.gatherDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:599)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.performDownloads(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:518)
    at org.eclipse.aether.internal.impl.DefaultArtifactResolver.resolve(DefaultArtifactResolver.java:436)
```

And this is the BOM I am using.  I am not sure if the problem seems to be with the BOM file or a issue with Maven (Version 3.2.1).

AS far as I can tell, without the site goal running fine I can not run JaCoCo or Cobertura or Findbugs.

```
<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.wildfly</groupId>
            <artifactId>wildfly-parent</artifactId>
            <version>8.1.0.Final</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```